# Gutenberg/React pass dynamic property to filter function

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using [Gutenberg block filters](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blocklistblock) to try and add a dynamic class name to the block’s wrapper component in the editor.

```
registerBlockType( name, {

    title: __( 'My Block' ),

    parent: [ 'myplugin/myblock' ],

    category: 'common',

    attributes: attributes,


    edit( { attributes, setAttributes, className } ) {      

        const { someName } = attributes;

        /* how can I pass someName from here to customClassName? */

        return (
            /* render something */
        );
    },

    save( { attributes } ) {

        const { someName } = attributes;

        /* how can I pass someName from here to customClassName? */

        return (
            /* render something */
        );
    },
});



const customClassName = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        return <BlockListBlock { ...props } className={ someName } />;
    };
}, 'customClassName' );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockListBlock', 'myplugin/myblock', customClassName );
```

The issue: `someName` in constant `customClassName` is undefined.

How can I pass `someName` from the edit or save function to the constant `customClassName`? Which will be used in `wp.hooks.addFilter`.

Note: I can't add `wp.hooks.addFilter` or `customClassName` directly in the edit or save function. It will cause repeating.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this, Can you clarify please?

Comment: Ok I revised the question

Comment: What is the purpose of `customClassName` component? Is it just to add `someName` class or is there more?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb to add a class name which will be dynamic

Comment: Will the class name be `someName` or will it do some extra logic on top of it? I'm asking because as it stands, the custom filter seems somewhat redundant.

Comment: Obviously it will not be someName. That is just an example to keep it simple.. as I said, the class name will be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someName is an attribute, you can access it as

```
className={props.attributes.someName}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple Typo here :)

```
return <BlockListBlock className={ props.someName } { ...props } />;
```

> ***NOTE***: I would like to make props able to override the className if
>   needed.

**Another solution:**

```
return <BlockListBlock { ...props } className={ [props.someName, props.className] } />;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I guess you make a mistake in your question. surely, the `someName` value exists in `attributes` object and it is part of `props` object, so you can access it as simple as below:

```
const customClassName = createHigherOrderComponent(( BlockListBlock ) => {
  return ( props ) => {
    return <BlockListBlock {...props} className={props.attributes.someName} />;
  };
}, 'customClassName');
```

And another thing I want to say is that doesn't need curly braces and `return` functions for your code:

```
const customClassName = createHigherOrderComponent(
  BlockListBlock => props => (
    <BlockListBlock {...props} className={props.attributes.someName} />
  ),
  'customClassName'
);
```